# Net Core- add data to different model

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, razor, model, e-commerce

I am pulling the extra materials on the order page in my project. Since the model on this page is `product`, I need to run a `cart` class to add to cart. But I don't know how to do this with `asp-for`. How can I add data for class `cart` because the model on the page is `product`?

```
@if (product.ProductExtras.Any())
{
    <h5>Ekstra Malzemeler</h5>
    <ul class="clearfix">

        @foreach (var extra in product.ProductExtras)
        {
            <li>
                <label class="container_check">
                    @extra.Extra.Name<span>+ @extra.Extra.Price.ToString("c2")</span>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: You can create compound data view model that will include `cart` and `product` to be able access both classes.

Comment: Product listing is done on this page. I also want to send post by card. So I am using ienumarable<product> as model. If I use a viewmodel like this, how will I perform both product listing and cart insertion? So how should I define the model and how should I apply it? can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

Include your `cart` class and `product` class in a single class, and use this class in the view, you can access the data of both the `cart` class and the `product` class.

Like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    //Choose the data type depending on your needs
    public List<cart> cart { get; set; }
    public List<product> product { get; set; }
}
```

For more details you can refer to [this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/).

**Update:**

I try to send a post request with the state of the checkbox, maybe that's what you mean.
Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            ViewModel viewmodel = new ViewModel();
            viewmodel.product = new List<Product>();
            viewmodel.product.Add(new Product() {Id =1,Name="Product1" });
            viewmodel.product.Add(new Product() { Id = 2, Name = "Product2" });
            viewmodel.product.Add(new Product() { Id = 3, Name = "Product3" });
            return View(viewmodel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Test([FromBody]ViewModel viewmodel)
        {
            //your own processing logic
            return Json(viewmodel);
        }
```

View:

```
@model _2022080202.Models.ViewModel

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.product[0].Id)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.product[0].Name)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.product) {
            <tr>
                <td name = "Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
                <td name = "Name">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="@item.Id" /></td>
            </tr>
    }
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var id = $(this).val(); //The value bound in the checkbox
            var row = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
            ProductId = row.find("[name='Id']").text();
            ProductName = row.find("[name = 'Name']").text();
            var data = { ProductId: parseInt(ProductId), ProductName: ProductName };
            var cart = new Array();
            cart.push(data);
            var viewmodel = { cart: cart};

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: '/Home/Test',
                data: JSON.stringify(viewmodel),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result) {
                    //your own processing logic
                },
                error: function(error) { }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I send all the data out, you can just send an ID if you want and then do the following in the controller.

Test Result:
[image]

Comment: Product listing is done on this page. I also want to send post by card. So I am using ienumarable<product> as model. If I use a viewmodel like this, how will I perform both product listing and cart insertion? So how should I define the model and how should I apply it? can you give an example?

Comment: Do you want to send the post by checking the checkbox? @Ramazan Musluoğlu

Comment: yes that will happen. I need the extraId value that the already selected checkboxes have. I want to get the extraid value of the selected checkboxes.

Comment: I updated the answer, maybe it's what you want. @Ramazan Musluoğlu